# How To Use CRUD in ASP.Net MVC with EntityFramework CodeFirst in Pattern IUnitofwork

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I Have a PhoneBook Project in MVC and use IUnitOfWork .
but I dont Know that How do this project.
the link of the project :
http://www.mediafire.com/download/jy0b5ins5eisy5t/MvcAppPhoneBook.rar

please complate thie project for me

i'm doing CRUD in this project.

Comment: Are you trying to understand UnitOfWork pattern? Please elaborate your question.

Comment: yes but i dont know how to use ViewModel in ServiceLayer And Controllers And Views

Answer (score 0):

I've used generic repo and UoW in my projects as below. You can take reference of this to complete your project. I usually have 4 layer solution architecture:

1. Core

   - Model classes
2. Data

   - Generic Repo and UoW
   - DbContext
   - Code first migrations
3. Web

   - applications solution with dependency injection implementation (e.g.Ninject)
4. Test

   **Model classes**

   ```
   public class User
   {
           public int Id { get; set; }
           public string Name { get; set; }
   }

   public class Course
   {
           public int Id { get; set; }
           public string Name { get; set; }
   }
   ```

**MyDbContext.cs:**

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public MyDbContext() : base("name=DefaultConnection”)
        {
        }

        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }

    }
```

**Unit of Work:**

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
    {
        //private variable for db context
        private MyDbContext _context;
        //initial db context variable when Unit of Work is constructed
        public UnitOfWork()
        {
            _context = new MyDbContext();
        }
        //property to get db context
        public MyDbContext Context
        {
            //if not null return current instance of db context else return new
            get { return _context ?? (_context = new MyDbContext()); }
        }
        //save function to save changes using UnitOfWork
        public void Save()
        {
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

**Generic Repository:**

```
public class RepositoryBase<T> : IRepositoryBase<T> where T : class
    {
        protected readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
        private readonly IDbSet<T> _dbSet;

        public RepositoryBase(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
        {
            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
            _dbSet = _unitOfWork.Context.Set<T>();
        }

    public virtual void Save()
        {
            _unitOfWork.Save();
        }

        public virtual void Add(T entity)
        {
            _dbSet.Add(entity);
            _unitOfWork.Save();
        }
    //Similarly you can have Update(), Delete(), GetAll() implementation here

    }
```

**Entity Repository inheriting from generic repo:**

```
public class UserRepository:RepositoryBase<User>,IUserRepository
    {
        public UserRepository(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork) : base(unitOfWork)
        {
        }
    //Here you can also define functions specific to User
    }
```

**controller.cs**

```
public class UserController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IUserRepository _dbUserRepository;

        public UserController(IUserRepository dbUserRepository)
        {
            _dbUserRepository = dbUserRepository;
        }

        // GET: /User/
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
        var users = _dbUserRepository.GetAll();

            return View(users.ToList());
        }

       //Other CRUD operations

}
```

Comment: Your implementation is not decoupled. You still depend on a `DbContext` (that you expose through the `IUnitOfWork.Context`. In EF, `IUnitOfWork` would model a `DbContext` and your repository would usually model a `DbSet<T>`. The UnitOfWork implementation of `DbContext` exposes the interface of the repository and instantiate the concrete implementation.